# Check if values in the array are even and if true return true

Tags: c, algorithm, function, loops

This is what I've done so far but the result is always 1 no matter if the array has odd or even numbers inside. What am I doing wroing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int vector[10]={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};
    bool function(int i){
        for(i=0,i<10,i++){
            if(vector[i]%2==0){
                return true;
                }
            return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are always returning on the first iteration… I.e. your code never gets to check the elements after the first elements.

Comment: Do you mean if *all* the values are even?

Comment: AFAIK nested functions are non-standard C.

Comment: Your braces don't match up... this shouldn't compile as is.  Also, defining a function inside another function isn't standard -- at best it relies on a compiler extension.  And you never call the function anyway.  Maybe post real code?

Comment: To start with 1. The for loop is messy 2. The `function` is never called 3. You've an extra `}` in the end. 4. You missed the return for the `int main`  and so..

Comment: uhm sorry.. (?) I started today with C and I probably messed up everything. furthermore I found out that I wasn't editing the main.c file so that's why I had no visual feedbacks of what I was doing wrong and that's why I had no warnings from codeblocks (probably?)

Answer (score 4):

If to follow the C Standard then you may not define a function inside another function.

Nevertheless the main problem with your function (apart from syntax errors as for example the invalid for statement) is using the return statement for the first element of the array independently on whether it is odd or even.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_even( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && a[i] % 2 == 0 ) i++;

    return i == n;
}

#define N 10

int main( void )
{
    int vector[N] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 };

    printf( "All elements are even: %d\n", is_even( vector, N ) );
}
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 1):

For loop should use `;` between entries, not `,`.  You are never looping.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

...

Honestly, I would expect your compiler to throw at least a warning on this statement as it is missing elements of a basic for loop.

Next, you need to move your

```
return false;
```

outside the for loop or it will never iterate past the first entry.

Last, defining `function` within `main` is a not standard in C.  Make it it's own function and things will be happier.

Comment: I made the correction suggested by you (thanks for pointing the comma issue out, this is my first day of C so I'm doing a lot of mistakes) but I don't know if I should leave the main empty .. is this the proper way to test a program? or maybe I can just make the main a bool function and go on?

Anyway the result is 1 again, there something I'm probably missing. CodeBlocks doesn't show any warning when I build the file..

Comment: ok, now I know what I was doing wrong. I was editing other c files and not the main.c . this is why I wasn't receiving warnings and this is why I always had same result no matter the changes

Answer (score 1):

Because you are returning it on a final iteration. You should return `false` when you have checked the whole array, not in middle.

Also, your function was never get called and so you can update it using C semantic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool check_even(int vector[], int size){
    int i;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(vector[i] % 2==0) { 
           return true;
        }
        // return false; shift this to out of for block
     }
  return false;
}


int main(){
    int vector[10]={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};

    bool is_even = check_even(vector, 10); // here function will get called

    return 0 // always return with main
}
```

Comment: @ryyker typo mistake. Updated it.

Comment: I tried following your suggestion and when I run the file it says "Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 0.016 s". Is this what I should expect?

Comment: Yes. `is_even` contains the value i.e. true (1) or false (0). You can print is using `printf("%d\n", is_even)`